# Energy released in nuclear fission

Tags: energy-conservation, nuclear-physics, mass-energy, binding-energy

In induced fission of U-235, neutrons are bombarded at the U-235, producing U-236. This U-236 then undergoes fission:

U-235 + n --> U-236 --> Ba-141 + Kr-92 + 3n

As far as I understand, the energy released in fission is gained as kinetic energy of the products, and also released as gamma photons/beta particles and neutrinos when the products decay. My confusion lies in calculating the energy released, as I do not think the method in the textbook is correct.

The absorbed neutron loses nuclear potential energy. This causes the binding energy of U-236>U-235, meaning the rest mass of U-236 is less than the rest mass of U-235 + n. This increase in binding energy is then used to deform the nucleus into a double-lobed drop allowing the two fragments to separate due to electrostatic repulsion.

The two fragments formed have a greater binding energy per nucleon than U-236, and hence the binding energy of the fragments is greater than U-236. (In turn causing the mass of the products to decrease). However this increase in binding energy is gained as kinetic energy of the products/released as gamma photons etc.

Mo1 = Mass(U235+n)

Mo2= MassU236

Mo3 = Massfissionproducts

B1=binding energy of U235

B2=binding energy of U236

B3 = binding energy of fission    products

The energy **released** in fission is due to the increase in binding energy **B3-B2.** The increase in binding energy **B2-B1** is used to deform the nucleus - it is **not 'released'.** 
Therefore the energy released in the fission process = (Mo2-Mo3)c^2.

However my textbook states that the energy released in the fission process =(Mo1-Mo3)c^2. I don't understand this as they are including the energy to deform the nucleus, (Mo1-Mo2)c^2, when this is not actually released.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In principle the energy released is the total energy in (mass of $^{235}U$ + energy of thermal neutron) minus the total rest mass of the fission products. In practice, the neutron coming in is thermal (moderated), and has an energy of a few eV, which we can neglect. This means we can compute the energy released from the difference in the rest masses of the "in" and "out" particles. The rest mass of $^{236}U$ is not relevant, because what is formed is an excited state.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the mass has decreased partly because the neutron has lost NPE, which has released energy to deform the nucleus. So why are we saying that the total decrease in mass is the energy released?

Comment: Your initial state is uranium and a well separated neutron. There is no potential energy.

Comment: But doesn't the neutron binding to the nucleus release energy? I thought that when the neutron gets in range to be acted on by the SNF, then it loses potential energy.

Comment: "The absorbed neutron loses nuclear potential energy. " That is incorrect for those nuclei which fission. The initially formed $^{236}$U is **not** in the ground state, but has about 6.6 MeV of extra energy known as the activation energy. That extra energy is what produces the fission, and is only a part of the energy released. But you can't double-count it. Occasionally, the system throws off this energy in the form of gamma rays in a process known as radiative absorption, and no fission takes place for that specific nucleus.

Comment: I thought that if a nucleon was acted on by the SNF then it loses nuclear potential energy. Is the U236 nucleus formed in an excited state just due the kinetic energy of the neutron?

Comment: We are studying fission of $^{235}U$. This is what nuclear engineers care about. In principle $^{235}U$ is already unstable to spontaneous fission, but the rate is unobservable small. So we need a thermal neutron (which brings in essentially no energy, except its rest mass). Everything about the intermediate state (that it is deformed, that it is excited) is irrelevant to the energy balance.

Comment: So why is the U236 formed in an excited state?

Comment: You could have asked about the energy release in $^{236}U$ fission. But this question is ill defined, because you would need to know precisely which excited state was populated (although in the case of thermal $n+^{235}U$ fission we know: The excited state energy jas to match the entrance channel).

Comment: It is excited because of energy conservation. The energy of the groud state of $^{236}U$ does not accidentally match $n+^{235}U$,

Comment: So is this energy coming from the neutrons rest energy?

Comment: No, it's just the fact that the nuclear structure of $^{236}U$ is different from that of $^{235}U$. Some of it is indeed the potential energy of the neutron, but there are other things as well (different deformation etc)

Comment: If some of it is potential energy of the neutron, then doesn't this mean that the neutron loses potential energy, and this causes the binding energy of the nucleus to increase.

Comment: Yes, but the point remain that in the reaction $n+^{235}U\to$ (compund nucleus) $\to$ (fission fragments) the binding energy of the compond nucleus is not relevant to fission energy release.